# Ruby Thread local variables

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex, activesupport

Ruby has native support for thread local variables since version **2.0**. However active_support/core_ext/thread.rb implements this feature in pure ruby for support of thread locals in earlier versions of Ruby. So, I wonder why should we use mutex in **_locals** method:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec1227a9cc682ebf796689ef0f329038162c421b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/thread.rb#L76

Answer (score 0):

`_locals` does two things:

```
def _locals
  # 1. Returns the local variable hash when defined
  if defined?(@_locals)
    @_locals

  # 2. Lazily instantiates a locals hash
  else
    LOCK.synchronize { @_locals ||= {} }
  end
end
```

That synchronization step is required to ensure that the `@_locals` is never cleared out during first access.

Consider the following scenario:

```
thread = Thread.new

# Say I run this statement...
thread.thread_variable_set('a', 1)

# In parallel with this statement...
thread.thread_variable_get(:a)
```

Both of those methods call `_locals`, and if they execute simultaneously, they may both end up at the lazy assignment step:

```
@_locals ||= {}
# Expands to...
unless @_locals
  @_locals = {}  # <-- We could end up here with both threads at the same time,
end              #     which jeopardizes any value that might have been set.
```

So imagine we had no mutex and that the setter completed execution while the getter had entered the lazy assignment step.  We've effectively lost any locals we set due to a thread collision. Calling synchronize on a mutex guarantee that the block executes to completion without any such collisions.

Note that the core extension will not be loaded for versions of Ruby which support accessing thread-local variables. See the very last line:

```
unless Thread.instance_methods.include?(:thread_variable_set)
```

Comment: I understand unless statement. But my question was about using mutex in active_support/core_ext/thread.rb

Comment: How can you run parallel read&write access on particular Thread? We talk about locals variable that relates to specific Thread.

Comment: Threads can potentially interact with one another or some higher process may interact with a thread while its running. This provides a layer of protection against collisions in those circumstances.

Comment: Ok. Then why there is no mutex synchronize block in thread_variable_set?

Comment: That's the programmers choice to make.